# VS Code using Remote SSH - How to open "local" terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am connected to a remote server via SSH and using the Remote - SSH plugin by VS Code to do so. However, when opening up a terminal, the default terminal is the terminal of the remote server. I know this makes a lot of sense but there are times where I'd like to actually use the local terminal from VS Code as well.

Is there any way to do this or is the terminal limited to the host that VS Code's session is established?

Answer (score 8):

If you can SSH back home, an easy way is to open a new terminal in VS Code and `ssh home`.

**EDIT** in fact, just search "terminal local" in the Command Palette. This feature exists out-of-the-box in VSCode, see : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/730

Comment: When I try to `cmd-shift-p > creat integrated terminal (local)` on MacOS 12, I'm getting "The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "/usr/bin/zsh" does not exist." (`which zsh` prints `/bin/zsh`). I tried `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/zsh /bin/zsh` on my local machine, but I'm getting "Operation not permitted" error.

Comment: I made it work with `cmd-shift-p` > `Open remote settings (JSON) (SSH-...)` > adding this: `"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh"`